# Characters missing when using VNC with 22.04

Tags: keyboard, vmware, vnc

I am remoting into a desktop with screen sharing and TightVNC. Recently I added a VM of 22.04 to VMWare Workstation, when I type in it characters often are missed, meaning I have to type most characters two or three times for them to be picked up. It doesn't happen with any other version of Ubuntu I have installed in the same way, and is the only VM to do so. Any idea what that might be?

Answer (score 1):

I get occasional lost characters, but mostly caplock turns itself on randomly.  I also get strings of repeater characters from time to time.  It's usable, but PAINFUL!

I suspect the issue has something to do with N-key rollover as it usually goes  nuts when I'm typing like crazy.  I haven't figured out how to reproduce the issue on demand.

BTW I've disabled Wayland thinking that was the issue, but it's not.

I have been using TightVNC from Windows for years and it has worked flawlessly with all LTS releases between 14.04 and 20.04.  This clearly a 22.04 issue.  Wish I had an answer, but I don't.  Hopefully someone with more knowledge will take pity on us.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it is really painful, it is a constant issue for me when remoting, need to try and test more to see if there is anything that can reduce it.